# how to use mongoimport (from mongotools) in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, winforms, mongoimport

im learning how to connect mongoDB with c#

my objective is to import a student.json file and add it to my db in a new collection using c#

this is what im trying to use :

```
            var command = @"mongoimport --db test --collection colectn2 --file c:\tmp\students.json --jsonArray";

            //get database
            IMongoDatabase testDB = dbClient.GetDatabase("test");

            var result = testDB.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToJson());
```

when i try this in my cmd line works fine.

The problem: mongoimport doesnt import the json file when i try to run it from the c# application but it does import it when i use the same statement from the command line.

Your help is highly appreciate it !

Comment: What goes wrong? You need to state what your problem is.

Comment: `mongoimport` is a stand-alone executable tool, not a command in MongoDB you can use.

Comment: @PalleDue The problem: mongoimport doesnt import the json file when i try to run it from the c# application but it does import it when i use the same statement from the command line.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit do you know if mongoimport has been added into c# by any chance? i cant find any resources

Comment: Yes, of course because it is a command line tool! If you like to run it then use `Process.Start("mongoimport.exe ...")` Maybe start reading [MongoDB Driver Quick Tour](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.15/getting_started/quick_tour/)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late to answer but here it is :
You can use command line in order to import your data like this.

```
string command = $"mongoimport --uri=\"{uri}\" --db={dbName} --collection={collectionName} --jsonArray --authenticationDatabase=admin --file={filePath}";
var task = Process.Start("CMD.EXE", $"/C {command}").WaitForExitAsync();
```

I have to mention that in order to not get ***mongoimport is not recognized as an internal or external command*** error , you have to copy/paste the mongoimport.exe file inside C:\Windows\System32 path.